# Unexpected result for TypeScript Interfaces using Quicktype 'allOf'

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, discriminator

We are changing from **JSON Type Definition** to **JSON Schema** and are now using Quicktype to convert the JSON Schemas to TypeScript Types.
For the most part, Quicktype is doing its job very well, but aparently it can't convert **Discriminators**, or the JSON Schema equivalent **allOf** with **if-then**. It seems to just ignore the allOf...
Did we do anything wrong?

The bash command we use to convert JSON Schema to TypeScript:

```
quicktype -o ./src/typings.ts --just-types --acronym-style camel --src-lang schema
```

### Expected Result

```
export type CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1 = CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Person | CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Company;

export interface CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Person {
    type: CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Type.Person;
    customerKey: string
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
}
export interface CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Company {
  type: CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Type.Company;
  customerKey: string
  companyName: string
}

export enum CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Type {
    Company = "COMPANY",
    Person = "PERSON",
}
```

### Actual Result

```
export interface CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1 {
    type: CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Type;
}

export enum CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Type {
    Company = "COMPANY",
    Person = "PERSON",
}
```

### Our JSON Schema File:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Command: Creates a new customer (Types: COMPANY | PERSON)",
    "subject": "commands.crm.customers.createCustomer",
    "authenticationRequired": true
  },
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "$id": "CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "COMPANY",
        "PERSON"
      ]
    },
    "customerKey": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "type"
  ],
  "$comment": "discriminator",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "COMPANY"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "companyName": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "companyName"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "PERSON"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
        },
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "title": "CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Person",
        "required": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your schema to use `oneOf` rather than `if, then`...these are the results. Still leaves a lot to be desired.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "metadata": {
        "description": "Command: Creates a new customer (Types: COMPANY | PERSON)",
        "subject": "commands.crm.customers.createCustomer",
        "authenticationRequired": true
    },
    "type": "object",
    "$id": "CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "PERSON"
                    ]
                },
                "customerKey": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "type",
                "firstName",
                "lastName"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "COMPANY"
                    ]
                },
                "companyName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "customerKey": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
                "type",
                "companyName"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
export interface Typings {
    customerKey?: string;
    firstName?:   string;
    lastName?:    string;
    type:         Type;
    companyName?: string;
}

export enum Type {
    Company = "COMPANY",
    Person = "PERSON",
}
```

```bash
quicktype --out typings.ts --just-types  --acronym-style camel --src-lang schema --src schema.json --lang ts
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where `additionalProperties: false` and `allOf` cause a lot of confusion and heartache.

Prior to 2019-09, this combination of keywords conflicts with how many people believe it should work. In reality, it validates each schema separately: the root, and each `allOf` subschema. When you add `additionalProperties: false` to the root schema, it means no other properties are allowed, regardless of how many subschemas define other properties.

take this example: Every possible schema will fail for `additionalProperties` except the following instances.

```json
{}
```

```json
true
```

```json
false
```

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    {"properties": {"name": {"type": "string"}}},
    {"properties": {"age": {"type": "number"}}}
  ]
}
```

In order to fix your issue from a **JSON Schema perspective**, you need to modify the root schema to include the `additionalProperties` you would expect from the `allOf` subschemas. Giving each of them a `true` boolean schema is sufficient for the validator to recognize these properties are allowed.

You will also notice in the `if, then`, the `type` property must be defined again with a `true` boolean schema to be recognized as a valid property because you have set `additionalProperties: false` once more in the `then` statement.

Fixing these issues in your schema doesn't guarantee QuickType will support this schema. You may need to further follow up with their project maintainers.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Command: Creates a new customer (Types: COMPANY | PERSON)",
    "subject": "commands.crm.customers.createCustomer",
    "authenticationRequired": true
  },
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "$id": "CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "COMPANY",
        "PERSON"
      ]
    },
    "customerKey": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "companyName": true,
    "firstName": true,
    "lastName": true
  },
  "required": [
    "type"
  ],
  "$comment": "discriminator",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "COMPANY"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "companyName": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "companyName"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "PERSON"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "type": true
        },
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "title": "CreateCustomerCommandPayloadV1Person",
        "required": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not your expected results, but this is what QuickType came up with after modifying this schema.

```js
export interface Typings {
    companyName?: any;
    customerKey?: string;
    firstName?:   any;
    lastName?:    any;
    type:         Type;
}

export enum Type {
    Company = "COMPANY",
    Person = "PERSON",
}
```

```bash
 quicktype -o typings.ts --just-types --acronym-style camel -s schema schema.json
```